# Dynamically configure StreamingAttachment properties

Tags: jax-ws

I'm developing JAX-WS web service. My Java class looks like (with annotations):

```
@MTOM
@WebService(endpointInterface = "mtomtest.wsserver.mtomserver")
@StreamingAttachment(parseEagerly=true, memoryThreshold=4000000L, dir="D:\\projects\\123\\files\\temp")
public class mtomserverImpl implements mtomserver {
```

Note hardcoded values for StreamingAttachment annotation. I want to be able to dynamically initialize those values from my code - any way of dong that? So I want to do something like (on server):

```
configureMyself() {
    setMemoryThreshold(12345);
    setTempDir("c:\\mydirectory");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution - explained it here - http://www.java.net/forum/topic/glassfish/metro-and-jaxb/dynamically-configure-streamingattachment-properties